# Multiple layouts with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: Desired structure]

I am building an Angular app and hitting a bit of a snag in how to handle the home page. The home page is 90% different - only the header stays the same - in there I have directives that show user login state for ex.

To make use of routing/templates etc I'd ideally like to have my ngview in the white area of sample shown - that all works fine - just not sure how to build the home page. It doesn't need an ngview area persay since it's the only one of it's kind. I don't want to make it as a second apps however as that seems wasteful and would reload everything.

Googling this brings up suggestions of replacing the white area with a directive but then I think I would lose the whole routing/template benefit.

Alternatives I have seen have code to determine if on home and load a body CSS class etc but that is not ideal either as the content is so different.

UI Router is a possibility but I'd like to avoid prebeta stuff if possible.

Suggestions?

Comment: Might ng-cloak work to hide the views until the user is logged in?

Comment: @StevenScott not in this case - it's an entirely different layout and I cringe at the thought of loading 2 layouts for every page and using css to deal with them. I am having decent success with UI Router so I might go with that if nothing else comes up. They say it's stable so we'll see....

Comment: This is a very common/recurring problem, it's surprising to me there is still no answer to this question 2 years after

Comment: @edgh and still in 2017, not much has changed as far as I can tell. I have a similar issue and have been thinking about how to solve it for a while now without much luck. Only hacks like timeouts..

Answer (score 1):

You could have this:

index.html:

```
<body>

  ...header..

  <div ng-if="isHomePage()">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!isHomePage()">
    <div ng-include="'shell.html'"></div>
  </div>

  ...footer..

</body>
```

home.html (with route '/')

```
...your home page html...
```

shell.html (any route different than '/')

```
<div>
    <div>
       <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <aside><aside>
</div>
```

finally, add `isHomePage()` to your root scope

```
$rootScope.isHomePage = function() {
    return $location.path() == '/';
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This uses uirouter which is the answer nowadays. This question is very old and was written before UI Router was stable. I should delete it as its not relevant anymore.